# ViewModel with several LiveData and UseCases

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-lifecycle, android-livedata

I am currently experimenting with making a viewmodel for Fragment. My approach is to use exactly one viewmodel for one fragment. I have several use cases for different scenarios ex. to fetch books, to get info about a book. All these use cases happens in one Fragment. Now I made a ViewModel with 3 UseCases independent from each other and 3 corresponding LiveDatas.

I am wondering if it is a good practice. Any suggestions?

```
class GetBooksViewModel
@Inject constructor(private val getBooksUseCase: GetBooksUseCase,
private val getBooksListsUseCase: GetBooksListsUseCase,
private val getInfoByBookUseCase: GetInfoByBookUseCase) :
    BaseViewModel() {

var books: MutableLiveData<java.util.LinkedHashMap<String, Book?>> = MutableLiveData()
var bookLists: MutableLiveData<List<BookList>> = MutableLiveData()
var infos: MutableLiveData<List<BookInfo>> = MutableLiveData()

//methods for fetching data will be below

fun getBooks() =
getChannelsUseCase() {
  it.either(::handleFailure, ::handleGetBooksUseCase)
}

private fun handleGetBooksUseCase(response: 
 java.util.LinkedHashMap<String, Channel?>) {
this.books.value = response
}
```

inside Fragment

```
getBooksViewModel = viewModel(viewModelFactory) {
  observe(books, ::getBooks)
  observe(booksLists, ::getBooksLists)
  observe(bookInfos, ::doSomethingWithInfos)
  failure(failure, ::handleFailure)
}
```

Comment: Personally I think (and this is just an opinion, but) the name "UseCase" for api fetch tasks is quite unfortunate. Yes, I know it comes from the [Android Clean Architecture document from 2014](https://fernandocejas.com/2014/09/03/architecting-android-the-clean-way/),  but on the other hand if you think about the UML UseCase Diagram, then fetching data is not user interaction, not a feature, it's just an implementation detail. I prefer to call them "RemoteTask". Once you know it's just a "task" and not what the user cares about, then you can figure out what to do with it, and when it should run

Answer (score 0):

A combined model can be used instead of three different `models` and `liveData` like this :-

```
class CombinedModel( var map : MutableLiveData<java.util.LinkedHashMap<String, Book?>, var books : MutableList<BookList>, var infos = MutableList<BookInfo> )
```

And the livedata can be like :-

```
var response: MutableLiveData<CombinedModel>
```

*Hence only one `Observer` logic can take care of all three data* in the activity